# Framework 7. Theme page not affectting whole appp

Tags: html-framework-7

I have done this code using Framework7

```
<div class="page" data-name="theme">
    <div class="page-content">

        <div class="block-title">Elige el color del tema:</div>
        <div class="list">
            <ul>
            <li><label class="item-radio item-content">
                    <input name="color-radio" value="red" type="radio"><i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
                    <div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">Red</div></div>
                </label></li>

            <li><label class="item-radio item-content">
                    <input name="color-radio" value="green" type="radio"><i class="icon-radio"></i>
                    <div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">Green</div></div>
                </label></li>
            </ul>
        <!--And so on with other colors-->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

That page uses this DOM script:

```
$$('input[name="color-radio"]').on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          $$('.view').removeClass('color-theme-pink color-theme-blue color-theme-red color-theme-black color-theme-gray color-theme-orange color-theme-yellow color-theme-green color-theme-white');
          $$('.view').addClass('color-theme-' + $$(this).val());
        }
      });
```

The problem here is that it doesn't work. I open the HTML code on main-view but when I click each radio, the theme doesn't change.

If I put the theme HTML on main index file, it works.

Could you help me?

Comment: where is the script located is it index page or not

Comment: It's a file called into the index.html

Answer (score 0):

In Framework7 you need to add any scripts either in index page or in app.js page.

```
$$('input[name="color-radio"]').on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          $$('.view').removeClass('color-theme-pink color-theme-blue color-theme-red color-theme-black color-theme-gray color-theme-orange color-theme-yellow color-theme-green color-theme-white');
          $$('.view').addClass('color-theme-' + $$(this).val());
        }
      });
```

The above script must be added to index page or app.js file. if you add any scripts in other pages those scripts will not work. 
All scripts must be in either index page/app.js

Comment: I forgot to said that it is called from app.js

Comment: alert $$(this).val(); and see what you are getting.